# convert quarter year to last date of quarter in R

Tags: r, zoo

I have an issue when I use `as.Date(as.yearqtr(test[,1],format ="%qQ%Y"),frac =1)`, but it returns an error,and quater-year didn't change to date. The error is:
`error in as.yearqtr(as.numeric(x)) (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

This is my dataframe in R.

```html
TIME   VALUE
1Q2019  1
2Q2019  2
3Q2019  3
4Q2019  4
```

The ideal output is

```html
TIME   VALUE
2019-03-31  1
2019-06-30  2
2019-09-30  3
2019-12-31  4
```

Comment: I get no error when I tried your code but we can't be absolutely sure what .`test` contains unless we have it in a reproducible form.  Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and provide the output of `dput(test)`  in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to Date with zoo and get the last date of the quarter with `frac`. We use some RegEx to rearrange in `zoo`'s suitable format:

```
df$TIME=as.Date(as.yearqtr(gsub("(\\d)(Q)(\\d{1,})","\\3 Q\\1",df$TIME)),frac = 1)
 df
        TIME VALUE
1 2019-03-31     1
2 2019-06-30     2
3 2019-09-30     3
4 2019-12-31     4
```

Data:

```
df <-structure(list(TIME = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1Q2019", "2Q2019", 
"3Q2019", "4Q2019"), class = "factor"), VALUE = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: when i use your code, all date returns to NA. Does it means that the column attr have some issue?

Comment: I just used the data in the question, could you please add your actual data with `dput(head(df,n))`?

Comment: I updated the question. Add actual data into the original question. @NelsonGon

Comment: How do you want to deal with NAs?

Comment: Just keep NA as NAs

Comment: I got it. It's my table type issue. I converted table into DF. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return a vector of dates, given an input vector in the form of 1Q2019...

```
dateStrings <- c("1Q2019","2Q2019","3Q2019","4Q2019","1Q2020")

lastDayOfQuarter <- function(x){
     require(lubridate)
     result <- NULL
     months <-c(3,6,9,12)
     days <- c(31,30,30,31)

     for(i in 1:length(x)) {
          qtr <- as.numeric(substr(x[i],1,1))
          result[i] <- mdy(paste(months[qtr],days[qtr],(substr(x[i],3,6)),sep="-")) 
     }
     as.Date(result)

}
lastDayOfQuarter(dateStrings)
```

and the output:

```
>lastDayOfQuarter(dateStrings)
[1] "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
>
```