# parse quarters to dates, using "qr()" to last day in quarter

Tags: r, lubridate

My questing is kind of simuler to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414089/convert-quarter-year-to-last-date-of-quarter-in-r), but I'm using [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate). I have some string-`quarters` that I need translated into dates, but insted of getting the first day of the quarter like this,

```
# library(lubridate)
quaters <- c("2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2", "2019Q3", "2019Q4", "2020Q1")
 
yq(quaters)
# [1] "2018-10-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-07-01" "2019-10-01"
# [6] "2020-01-01"
```

I would like the laste day of the quarter. Like this,

```
yq(quaters, last) "!! NOT WOKRING CODE
# [1] "2018-12-31" "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31"
# [6] "2020-03-31"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add 3 months to every date and subtract 1 day to get last day of each quarter.

```
library(lubridate)
quaters <- c("2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2", "2019Q3", "2019Q4", "2020Q1")

yq(quaters) %m+% months(3) - 1
#[1] "2018-12-31" "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
```

---

Another similar option is to use `ceiling_date` with `unit` as `"quarter"` to get next quarters date and then subtract 1 day from it.

```
ceiling_date(yq(quaters), 'quarter') - 1
```

Comment: Nifty workaround! I would have imagined lubridate had a function to get the last date within years, months, weeks, quarters, etc. Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember any function in `lubridate` which gives last date for any week, month, quarter, year. All of them give the 1st day of everything.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearqtr(quaters), 1)
#[1] "2018-12-31" "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
```

#### data

```
quaters <- c("2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2", "2019Q3", "2019Q4", "2020Q1")
```